# How to create API in rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new to web service and Rails too. I have a doubt in creating API using rails 5. How do I create an API for a rails 5 application? I can find some tutorials for **API only** applications using rails 5. But I need both API and views in a single rails 5 application. How should I do that?

Comment: `rails new my_api --api` command creating new api only application. if you need api and views, create usual application(without api mode) and then render jsons/views in your controller methods

Comment: You're a bit confused. Api-only mode is specifically for api-only apps, which don't use views and don't need the overhead of loading unused code. You totally can create api endpoints in a regular rails app. Basically, an api endpoint is a controller action that renders json instead of html. That's it.

Comment: Thank you @SergioTulentsev. But how should I config the route for APIs?

Comment: @poombavai: just like you do with your regular controllers. Nothing different there.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev. Sorry if my doubts seems stupid. How should I view my API? For example. 192.168.1.59:3000/users/index would render my index page in html format. If I need it in JSON, then what should I do? My Android App should use my API. Then how should I give my API to them?

Comment: @poombavai: yeah, that's little too big a topic for a comment. :) BTW, "/users/index" is not a page that should display list of users (by rails convention). The correct page is "/users".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new rails project as usual:

```
$ rails new my_project
$ cd my_project
$ bundle
```

And then you can use `scaffold` to generate some code:

```
$ rails g scaffold Product name:string price:float
```

And migrate your database:

```
$ rails db:migrate # => update the database
```

You can now have a look at `app/controllers/products_controller.rb`

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /products/new
  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /products/1
  # PATCH/PUT /products/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /products/1
  # DELETE /products/1.json
  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price)
    end
end
```

As you can see there's `respond_to` in the `create` action. This is how you can respond to different request types.

Read more about it: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_to

Comment: Thank you @RaVeN. But how should I config my routes for an API?

Comment: Look at the `config/routes.rb`. They're automatically generated. You can use the same routes as you use to retrieve html, to trigger the `respond_to.json` you can append `.json` to the route: exapmle: `/products/1.json` (You can see the comments above every action how to reach them)

Comment: Thankyou @RaVeN. Rails is awesome. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

I've my own solution to build API very quickly https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/fake_api at least on the stage of prototyping.

Using this gem I was able to provide a skeleton of the API for Frontend team, later it was changed to regular rails controllers.

Answer (score 0):

While create a RESTful API, According to Rails 5 release notes, generating an API only application will:

1. Start the application with a limited set of middleware
2. Make the ApplicationController inherit from ActionController::API instead of ActionController::Base
3. Skip generation of view files,

I am listing down article/ Blog post's link read those:

- [Best Pratices for API only rails app](http://techtales.co/2017/08/31/building-api-rails/)
- [Rails Api only Web app](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/how-to-make-rails-5-api-only)
- [Rails Token based authentication: API only rails web app](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/token-based-authentication-with-ruby-on-rails-5-api)
- [Must read, Api only rails web app](https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/posts/building-a-restful-api-in-a-rails-application)
- [Read this also, rails api only web app](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-json-api-with-rails-5-part-one)
- [Restful API with rails](https://www.oreilly.com/content/how-a-restful-api-server-reacts-to-requests/)
- [Create a REST Api with Rails](https://medium.com/@oliver.seq/creating-a-rest-api-with-rails-2a07f548e5dc)
- [Create a REST Api with Rails 5](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/how-to-make-rails-5-api-only)

Read any one of the above blog and just go through others for getting additional details or for the knowledge purpose

Have a Great Coding! ‍‍

Answer (score 0):

Just build you regular rails app and when you need a API behavior on that method just respond with a json like this

```
def index
    @cards = Card.all
    render json: { status: 'Success', message: 'Loaded all cards', data: @cards }, status: :ok
end
```

If you really need the additional behavior from the controller to you can just take a regular controller and change the inheritance to something like this

```
class CardsController < ActionController::API
    #your code
end
```

For more information on this specifically checkout [Rails API Applications](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html)